# Non Prseable POM

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.18: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18
[ERROR] [FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Oscar Ochoa.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire\2.18\surefire-2.18.pom: end tag name  must be the same as start tag  from line 5 (position: TEXT seen ...\n  ... @31:10)  @ C:\Users\Oscar Ochoa.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire\2.18\surefire-2.18.pom, line 31, column 10

POM FILE

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
    <artifactId>specialsource-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <name>SpecialSourceMP</name>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:agaricusb/SpecialSourceMP.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:agaricusb/SpecialSourceMP.git</developerConnection>
        <url>git@github.com:agaricusb/SpecialSourceMP.git</url>
    </scm>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>GitHub</system>
        <url>https://github.com/agaricusb/SpecialSourceMP/issues</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mavenPluginVersion>3.5</mavenPluginVersion>
        <mavenVersion>3.0</mavenVersion>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
            <artifactId>SpecialSource</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Maven  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenPluginVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Plexus  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-digest</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mavenPluginVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.zlika</groupId>
                <artifactId>reproducible-build-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>strip-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The error message isn't referring to your pom -- please read it again!

Comment: The download of some pom's has failed either network/firewall/proxy issue https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2018/10/2018-10-13-maven-artifact-checksums-what/. second the plugin is really based on Maven 3.0? (12 years+) old..? Use a more recent version as base 3.2.5 over 3.8.6.. why using plexus-utils? Use maven-plugin-plugin most recent version as well... Define plugins for building (like compiler-plugin, recources plugin, deploy/install plugin and surefire/failsafe plugin as well...